# How to sort an associative array in PHP then find the string index of the results

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

If I have an associative array like this

```
$array = array();
$array['e01'] = '03/16/2012';
$array['e02'] = '03/14/2012';
$array['e05'] = '03/01/2014';
```

I'd like to sort the array by date then loop through the results to get the value of the index, i.e. e01, e02, e05.  I need that index to retrieve information from an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation on `asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).  This will sort it by value and let you access the key and value of each index:

```
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly for the date format he has.  It's sorting as a string.  Sorting dates as strings leads to incorrect results most times.

Comment: Great that worked very well.  Thanks for writing the few lines of code that do everything.  I will, however, add a user sort function to change string to time.

Comment: @Crashspeeder : Writing date/time in delocalized format for processing will allow you to ignore theses issues as delocalized goes from general to specific : `2012/01/10 12:00:01`. Years > Months > Days > Hours > Minutes > Seconds > ...

Comment: @JeffD Correct, that's why I said "most times".  Unfortunately it often happens that people store the date in a localized format instead of a sortable format.

Answer (score 1):

Try `uasort()` to sort your array:

```
function mysort($a, $b) {
    return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'mysort');
```

For getting the keys you can just use `array_keys()`

Comment: I think that I will have the right solution if I combine your suggestion of a uasort() with Stewart's answer.  His code does what I want and actually does the sorting.  But I'd rather add the strtotime function.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

When sorting an associative array, the keys and values change order but the key to value association will not change. So if key `e01` has a value of `03/16/2012`, even after a `uasort` (which is probably what you are looking for, see Crashspeeder's answer) `e01` will still have the value `03/16/2012`. If you want to change the order of the values while keeping the order of the keys:

- use array_keys to get the current order of the keys
- use usort (no need for uasort as we aren't preserving the keys) to sort the values by date
- use array_combine to make a new array with the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function.